# how to prevent page refresh while doing postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to display a pop up on each div click.the divs will create dynamically and each is boxes.I want to display some database values inside my pop up.I used hidden field(to get id) as a control parameter in sql datasource.To get the hidden field values on each click from c#,i used some _dopostback in javascript of my pop up plug in.
This causes page loading on every refresh and hence I cant display proper values in my popup on each click.
How can i avoid page refresh?
my javascript code:

in pop up function i called

```
__doPostBack('TestFunctionPostBack', comp_id);
```

c# code in page load

```
 this.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);

        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string eventTarget = (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
            string eventArgument = (this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

            if (eventTarget == "TestFunctionPostBack")
            {               
                HiddenField1.Value = eventArgument;

            }

        }
```

Comment: a post-back IS a page refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax to call server side method and then render content on UI
Look at the following example http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/09/29/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods.aspx

Comment: what if you're using SendGrid, which is not supported by AJAX apparently?

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX to avoid a full page post back.

You could easily add an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) for a partial post back. Or, even better, use a javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://encosia.com/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/).

Comment: what if you're using SendGrid, which is not supported by AJAX apparently?